# Kendo cascade-from firing too early?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo with angular.js, so in my first dropdown list, I have a model, which does capture the selection, but for some reason, when the event fires, the model isn't updated yet...

```
<input kendo-drop-down-list
       id="ddServiceLocations"
       k-options="ddServiceLocationsOptions"
       ng-model="enterClaimsService.model.serviceLocationSelection" />

<select kendo-drop-down-list
        id="ddJurisdictions"
        k-options="ddJurisdictionsOptions"
        k-cascade-from="'ddServiceLocations'"
        ng-model="enterClaimsService.model.jurisdictionSelection"></select>
```

When a selection is made in the first box, it does fire my `dataSource` for the second box, but the `enterClaimsService.model.serviceLocationSelection` object is undefined at that point? When that function exits, the model becomes defined no problem. How to get the model to update before the data source is called?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work but try to delay the initialization of the dropdownlist until this particular field is populated. How to do this is explained [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/AngularJS/introduction#delay-widget-initialization).